# Memory leak in NSMutableArray, can't autorelease

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am having trouble releasing tempArray below... tempArray is a leak and I have tried return [tempArray autorelease] and it causes a crash.   Does anyone know how to get rid of the memory leak in tempArray?

```
+(NSMutableArray*) returnTheArray:(NSString*)thePath forTheKey:(NSString*)theKey {

NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSString *plistPath;
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                          NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *testString = [thePath stringByAppendingString:@".plist"];
plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:testString];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:thePath ofType:@"plist"];

}
NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                                      propertyListFromData:plistXML
                                      mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                      format:&format
                                      errorDescription:&errorDesc];
 if (!temp) {
 CCLOG(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
 }

NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[temp objectForKey:theKey]];

return tempArray;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is that `returnTheArray` is not a name that the Analyzer will recognize as returning a retained value -- this is why it complains.  So either you rename the method or return an autoreleased value.  But if the latter you need to make sure that the "consumer" of the returned value appropriately deals with it -- retaining it if the value must persist beyond the next autorelease pool drain operation.

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks, I couldn't figure out how renaming the method would solve the issue so I changed to "return [tempArray autorelease]" and made sure to retain all "consumers" of the returned value.  Doesn't seem like an ideal solution but it resolved the memory leaks

Comment: The Analyzer bases it's expectations on the name of the method.  Those beginning with "new", "alloc", or "copy" are expected to return a retained value.  Other names are assumed to not return a retained value (thought they may or may not be autoreleased by the returning method -- they can also be known to be "safe" for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[temp objectForKey:theKey]];
```